# Thymeleaf does not found my templates (FileNotFoundException)

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Intellij and Thymeleaf is searching automatically at the root of the project and not under `src/main/resources/templates`

I have tried to add `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/src/main/resources/templates/` or `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/` in application.properties but it is not changing anything

I don't really know where the problem comes from.

Comment: You dont' have to set anything this must work out of the box. How do yo know that it is looking at the root?

Comment: The error starts with
`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "pathToMyProject\views\map.html")`

and the src/main/resources/templates part is missing

Comment: Try **removing** the template from the folder completely to check if the error message changes :)

Comment: And how do you return it from the Controller?

Comment: Just remove the files from the folder and test your application. If the error message changes, you have a proof that the problem is not that thymeleaf would search somewhere else. "An error happened during **template parsing**" does not sound to me like "file not found".

Comment: Like this: `return "views/map";` so it finds the html suffix

Comment: I remove everything under templates folder and it's still the same error

Comment: The error message never contains the path to `src/main/resources/templates`. Make sure that the String you return from your Controller method matches with the name of your template. If you do `return "views/map"`, then make sure there is a template at `src/main/resources/templates/views/map.html`. There is no need to set `spring.thymeleaf.prefix`.

Comment: yes I return this and the template exists, it used to work fine before but not after changing springboot and thymeleaf version (not sure if it is related)

Comment: the only way I can make it work is by returning "src/main/resources/templates/views/map" but it is not how it's supposed to work